# Getting all data from php page and send them to another page when using window.open() in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website that is already built, and I'm making a change request on it, when pressing on print icon, the page opens another page called print.php using javascript 
        window.open()
The problem is that I want when opening the print.php page which includes the same page to be printed, to take the data in input elements and fill it with these data in print.php page,
Now the print page appears to be empty inputs, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.opener** to get value from the parent window. so if you have text box in your  page having print icon and you want its value in print.php page you can get it like below

```
var txtval=window.opener.document.getElementById("txtbx_name").value;
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: the website is full of forms and I don't want to get every single input alone to get it, is it possible to duplicate the current page and view it in window??

Comment: If your purpose is only to print current page you can call window.print() function on click event of your print button

Comment: yes that's my purpose, but I want first to show a print preview page

Comment: It will display a print preview to you before printing